# Can't assign a numeric value to a field that is set to <Null>

Tags: arcpy, cursor, null

Within a feature class there's a number of records with a specific field (type double) set to . I've set up a cursor to assign those value a numeric number. However, I am getting an error.

This is the code:

```
import arcpy

working_folder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

#Input variables.
fc_Opt_All = os.path.join(working_folder, 'DATA\Optimity_Equipment.gdb', 'Optimity_All')

#Set initial number
last_location_id = 10000

field_names = ['LOCATION_ID']
i = 1
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_Opt_All, field_names) as cursor_1:
    for row_1 in cursor_1:
        if row_1[0] is None:
            row_1[0] = last_location_id + i
            i = i + 1
```

The error I get is the following:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The field 'LOCATION_ID' is numeric (double). I don't understand why it's saying it's a tuple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SearchCursor` returns a read-only cursor (so all rows are also read-only). You would need to use `UpdateCursor` instead.

The object returned by `SearchCursor` is a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) - similar to a list - , and each element of the tuple has its own type. Since the tuple in itself is immutable (read-only), you get the error at the tuple level and not at the individual element level.

Comment: Of course. Silly mistake :-). Thank you very much for spotting it.